# Codecademy Contact list Output Formatting

Tags: javascript, object

```
var friends = {
    bill:{
        firstName:"Bill",    
        lastName:"Gates",
        number:"(206) 555-5555",
        address: ["One Microsoft Way","Redmond","WA","98052"]
},
steve:{
       firstName:"Steve",   
       lastName:"Jobs",
       number: "(408) 555-5555",
       address: ['1 Infinite Loop','Cupertino','CA','95014']
   }
}

var list = function(friends) {
    for(var name in friends) {
    console.log(name);   
    }
};

var search = function(tname) {
    for(var name in friends) {
        if(friends[name].firstName == tname) {
            console.log(friends[name])
            return (friends[name])
        }
    }
};
```

This is the code i ende up with at the end of the Contact list [Assignment](https://www.codecademy.com/en/courses/javascript-beginner-en-3bmfN/0/8?curriculum_id=506324b3a7dffd00020bf661)

Then they asked if i could Output it as

```
First Name: Steve
Last Name: Jobs
Number: (408) 555-5555
Address: 1 Infinite Loop
        Cupertino, CA 95014
```

This I have no idea where to begin with
I only know as much javascript as i have learnt in this tutorial upto this point but if solutions requires external functions...a short description would be highly appreciated

Comment: I'm confused. Whats the question? You gave the output, but what exactly are you given in the beginning and what have you tried? Is the first snippet of code something you made?

Comment: It's like series of tasks and on reaching the last stage the code i have given is what we reach.When i run output comes in straight line going to next line whenever line ends...not orgnized. Now i have to make output like that

Answer (score 0):

```
var friends = {
    bill: {
    firstName: "Bill",
    lastName: "Gates",
    number: "(513) 555-5555",
    address: ["Somewhere", "Over the Rainbow"]
    },
steve: {
    firstName: "Steve",
    lastName: "Jobs",
    number: "(513) 555-5555)",
    address: ["Way up", "High"]
    }
};

var list = function (obj){
for(var key in obj){
console.log(key);
}
};

var search = function(name){
for(var key in friends){
    if(friends[key].firstName === name){
        console.log(friends[key]);
        return friends[key];
    }
    }
};
```

There you go :)

Answer (score 0):

You are going right you got the matching friends object, what you should do is access the properties of that object.

For accessing the property of the object, you can either use dot operator or pass the value in array, have a look at below example

```
   var bill = {
       firstName:"Steve",   
       lastName:"Jobs",
       number: "(408) 555-5555",
       address: ['1 Infinite Loop','Cupertino','CA','95014']
   }
```

For accessing the property of bill object

```
    >>> bill.firstName
    >>> Steve
    >>> bill.firstName = "John";
```

In this way you can access the property.

Once you access the property print the desire output like

```
     >>> console.log("FirstName: "+bill.firstName);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I was able to get output but it didnt look like what's been prescribed..how do i get new line in javascript

Comment: Just use "\n"  in console.log() for getting new line like this      console.log("Bill\nGates"), it will print Bill and Gates in separate line.